# How to save audio file after recording voice in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, file, audio, xamarin.forms, save

I am wondering how to save an audio file in Xamarin forms. I can get the location where to save to AppDataDirectory using Xamarin.Essentials:

```
var mainDir = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
```

But I am not sure how to save it in code, right after recording it using the NateRickard AudioRecorder Plugin:

```
var recordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();
var audioFile = await recordTastk;  //audioFile is of string datatype
```

Its same as saving/creating any binary file in C#? Say its same as saving an image file? And additionally do I need to use Dependency Injection to save it using platform specific code, or I can manage to only do it from the PCL code?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder#accessing-the-recorded-file) explicitly discuss this:

> **Accessing the Recorded File**
>
> There are multiple ways to access the recorded audio file path:
>
> - The Task-based API will return the file path when the task completes.    The Task can be awaited or use standard Task
>     continuation APIs.
> - The Event-based API will return the full path to the recorded audio file in the audioFile parameter of the AudioInputReceived event
>     handler.
> - The GetAudioFilePath () method on the AudioRecorderService class will return the recorded audio file path.
>
> These will all return null in the case that no audio has been recorded
>   yet or no audio was recorded/detected in the last recording session.
>
> Once you have the path to the recorded audio file, you can use
>   standard file operations (for native/.NET Standard) and/or a cross
>   platform file system abstraction like PCLStorage to get a stream to
>   the file data.